# Change JSON Format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i recently developed a rest service that accept json data in this format

```
{
    "foods": "food1, food2, food3",
    "qty": "1,2,3"
}
```

but my javascript generate this format

```
["food1","1","food2","2","food3","3"]
```

i wrote my rest in php

data's are from this table body

```
<tbody id="tr">
    <tr>
        <td class="data">food1</td>
        <td class="data">1</td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger removethisfood">-</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="data">food1</td>
        <td class="data">1</td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger removethisfood">-</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="data">food1</td>
        <td class="data">1</td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger removethisfood">-</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

my java script code

```
var tbl = $('#tr').map(function() {
     return $(this).find('td.data').map(function() {
       return $(this).html();
     }).get();
   }).get();
   console.log(JSON.stringify(tbl));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the format required by looping over each `tr` and adding the text of the relevant `td` to an array, before building the final object by joining the text of the arrays together, something like this:

```
var foods = [], qty = [];        
$('tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    foods.push($row.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    qty.push($row.find('td:eq(1)').text());
})

var obj = {
    foods: foods.join(','),
    qty: qty.join(',')
};
```

That said, your JSON format could be improved for clarity and simplicty of serialisation/deserialisation. It would make more sense to send an array with each item contained in an object with the parameters being its name and quantity, like this:

```
var obj = $('tr').map(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    return {
        food: $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
        qty: $row.find('td:eq(1)').text()
    }
}).get()
```

This output then looks like this:

```
[{
    "food": "food1",    
    "qty": "1"
},{
    "food": "food2",
    "qty": "1"
},{
    "food": "food3",
    "qty": "1"
}]
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/1mptq2oo/)

Comment: Could you show an example of the code you're using. As you can see from my fiddle, it should work fine.

Comment: thanks it works like a charm. now i use this to all my tables.